# Restarting every few minutes

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I have the following code:

```
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import sys

def stockchart(symbol):
    ts = TimeSeries(key='1ORS1XLM1YK1GK9Y', output_format='pandas')
    data, meta_data = ts.get_intraday(symbol=symbol, interval='1min', outputsize='full')
    print (data)
```

I wanted to know how can i 'keep alive' so to say so that there a new request every say 5 mins for data? Is while loop the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Don't forget to hit that green check-mark if my answer does it for you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like:

```
import time

while True:
    ts = TimeSeries(key='1ORS1XLM1YK1GK9Y', output_format='pandas')
    data, meta_data = ts.get_intraday(symbol=symbol, interval='1min', outputsize='full')
    print (data)
    time.sleep(300)
```

To achieve infinite recursion: [Python "while" loops](https://realpython.com/python-while-loop/)

And to wait for 5 minutes: [time.sleep](https://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-time-sleep-pause-wait-sleep-stop-your-code/)

Hope that answers your question!